# Angular 6 - Ngx Datable - Theme implemented partially

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

Good morning,

I have troubles to implement ngx-datable themes, it work partially: [material theme image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5bZ4.png)

When I check the console this message appear "DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost/index.map"

I implemented the code as recommended by the demo site.

It's mysterious because in the source code the footer and icons are present.

If someone know how to implemente it properly, or have an idea how I can resolve this it would be perfect. I have no more idea after two days of search.

Thank you

Here is my code :

it-home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { DemasyRequestService } from "../../shared/demasy-request.service";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-it-home",
  templateUrl: "./it-home.component.html",
  styleUrls: [
    "../../../../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css",
    "../../../../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css",
    "../../../../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css",
    "./it-home.component.css"
  ]
})
export class ItHomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public data = [];
  public columns = [];
  private dataSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private demasyRequestService: DemasyRequestService) {
    this.columns = [
      { prop: "Id" },
      { prop: "FirstName" },
      { prop: "LastName" },
      { prop: "ShortName" },
      { prop: "StartDate" }
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSubscription = this.demasyRequestService.getEmployees().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.data = [...data.obj];
        console.log(data.obj);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

it-home.component.html

```
<ngx-datatable #mydatatable class="material" [headerHeight]="50" [limit]="5" [columnMode]="'force'" [footerHeight]="100" [rowHeight]="'auto'"
  [trackByProp]="'updated'" [rows]="data" [columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
```

It works if I insert css code in public folder, but it sucks. It's a problem with webpack and source map loader I think. I will try to solve this but know nothing about webpack.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dev</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/release/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/release/themes/material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/release/assets/icons.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>

<app-root>Loading ...</app-root>

<script src="/js/app/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue?